# Why was the period between Domitian and Commodus so happy and prosperous?

Tags: history, roman-culture

In my introduction to *Meditations*, Edward Gibbon is quoted as saying that the period between the death of Domitian and the accession of Commodus was the happiest and most prosperous in human history. But I'm also aware that during Marcus Aurelius's lifetime there were several wars and even a plague that affected Rome. What is the basis for Edward Gibbon's statement? What made the period so happy and prosperous, and how does this compare/contrast with Roman eras before and after? Is this perhaps based on a common Roman expression or idea?

> If a man were called to fix the period in the history of the world during which the human race was most happy and prosperous, he would, without hesitation, name that which elapsed from the death of Domitian to the accession of Commodus.<sup>1</sup>

I would be interested in your thoughts as well as Roman sources.

---

<sup>1</sup> The Decline and Fall of the Roman Empire, ed. J.B. Bury (London, 1909), 1.85-6

Comment: Very interesting question! I am wondering, though, to what extent this is about Latin. Wouldn't be better to ask this question on History.SE?

Comment: @Cerberus Yeah, to repeat what I said on chat, I'm not sure myself but I fully defer to you guys. It does seem more appropriate to History although admittedly I have an affinity for this forum.

Comment: All you need to do is ask what the Roman sources have to say about it, and *voilà*, it's on topic here.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer That's a mighty good suggestion! Gets me out of the dilemma of being off-topic here and being attacked for lack of research on History.SE #scylla #charybdis

Comment: Were it up to me, all ancient questions would be here rather than there.

Comment: Good solution! I've added an extra line that points even more towards literature.

Comment: **Gibbon** does explain it in the same paragraph.

Comment: @AlexB. I think, as it stands now, an answer should give ancient sources for the idea.